# Getting socket error in Unity WebGL build

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, sockets, webgl

Hello and thank you for your help in advance!

I am working on a small WebGL project with Unity.Everything works fine in the Unity editor, but after building to WebGL, I get an ERROR when calling the API.[image]

This should open the user's browser for authentication.
Here is my code:

```
    public void InitiateTwitchAuth()
    {
        string[] scopes;
        string s;

        scopes = new[]
        {
            "user:read:email",
            "chat:edit",
            "chat:read",
            "channel:read:redemptions",
            "channel_subscriptions",
            "user:read:broadcast",
            "user:edit:broadcast",
            "channel:manage:redemptions"
        };

        _twitchAuthStateVerify = ((Int64) (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds).ToString();

        s = "client_id=" + twitchClientId + "&" +
            "redirect_uri=" + UnityWebRequest.EscapeURL(twitchRedirectUrl) + "&" +
            "state=" + _twitchAuthStateVerify + "&" +
            "response_type=code&" +
            "scope=" + String.Join("+", scopes);

        StartLocalWebserver();

        Application.OpenURL(twitchAuthUrl + "?" + s);
    }
```

```
    private void StartLocalWebserver()
    {
        HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();

        httpListener.Prefixes.Add(twitchRedirectUrl);
        httpListener.Start();
        httpListener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(IncomingHttpRequest), httpListener);
    }
```